# Nest can't resolve dependencies in completely identical files

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, resolve

Here is my module file

```
  imports: [
    AgentProfileModule,
    ExclusionModule,
    FeatureFlagModule,
    ShiftReviewModule,
    WorkerModule,
    ShiftsModule,
    PriorityAccessModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UrgentShiftsController, UrgentShiftsControllerV2],
  providers: [
    UrgentShiftsBatchNotificationService,
    UrgentShiftsNotificationService,
    UrgentShiftsNotificationRepository,
    UrgentShiftsRepository,
    UrgentShiftsService,
    WorkerDepartureService,
    UrgentShiftsNotificationLayeringService,
    FacilityProfileRepo,
  ],
  exports: [UrgentShiftsNotificationService, UrgentShiftsRepository],
})
export class UrgentShiftsModule {}
```

My issue is that the first controller is having zero dependency injection issues.  My second controller UrgentShiftsControllerV2 is not able to import UrgentShiftsService.

Here's the thing, even when I make the code in UrgentShiftsControllerV2 completely identical to UrgentShiftsController (which also imports UrgentShiftsService) it still gets the dependency issue.

Has anyone dealt with dependency issues from completely identical files before?

Comment: please, show us the error message. that's the reason why error messages exists.